# How to translate "original democracy" (= democraţie originală) (pejorative)?

Tags: translation

Some of the (political) analysts have been argued for years about the "originality" of democracy when speaking about the transition period after the communist period (1990+). The literal expression in Romanian is "democraţie originală" which can be translated to "original democracy" and is used pejoratively to describe a strange and convoluted way of implementing democracy.

However, [Google suggests](https://www.google.com/search?q=original%20democracy) that "original democracy" is connected to the first(?) democracy, the Athenian one.

Indeed, the English word [original](https://www.google.com/search?q=original) has two meanings:

> - present or existing from the beginning; **first or earliest**.
> - created personally by a particular artist, writer, musician, etc.; **not a copy.**

In Romanian there is no such ambiguity since there are two different words for these two concepts (*originar* vs. *original*).

**Question:** How to translate "original democracy" (= democraţie originală) to avoid ambiguity and keep the pejorative meaning?

Something that crosses my mind is "creative democracy", but this sounds quite positive to me.

Comment: You seem to mean "artificial" democracy or "idiosyncractic" democracy.

Comment: @Kris - yes. The expression might also be connected to the theory of forms without substance described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junimea#"Forms_without_substance").

Comment: Do you mean a "hollow" democracy or maybe the popular term "pseudo-" democracy?

Comment: @Kris - "pseudo-" democracy seems the best option to describe the concept, although it is rather harsh (Romania is considered a liberal democracy, at least according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberal_democracy) ). I think your comment(s) may be developed in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought of *creative* as well, through the parallel of "creative accounting". But you need a lot of context to get the joke, and originality/creativity is not as obviously a failing in politics as it is in accounting.

In fact, *original* can be used derogatorily in English ("that's... original"). And again, next to *democracy*, it just won't be obvious enough. That's the problem with translating irony: it's fragile.

If you have to go more literal, perhaps "Rube Goldberg democracy"? Or "make-it-up-as-you-go-along democracy"?